# Convert milli seconds into Date in DD/MM/YYYY format in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written a service which returns date in milliseconds , but I want to show it in format 'DD/MM/YYYY' , how can it be done?

Comment: you need to format the date, e.g. you can use this: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

var date = new Date(1324339200000);

date.toString("MMM dd"); // "Dec 20"

Answer (score 18):

use a `date` filter and specify format, for example:

```
{{date_in_milliseconds | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  time: any;
  date: any;
  calculateDate() {
    let milliSeconds = new Date().getTime();
    let date = new Date(milliSeconds);
    this.time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
    this.date = date.toLocaleDateString();
    console.log('time', this.time, this.date);
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

But I love [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) with own Angular filter.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 2:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(1495777991000)); //datetime in IST
var time= date.toLocaleTimeString() //retrieve time Fri May 26 2017 11:23:11
console.log(time) //11:23:11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pipe in angularjs. You can write following code in html file

```
{{date|date:'date format'}}
```